# WP8 compass app issue

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am learning the WP8 development. I am trying to incorporate compass in my application. I have found nice tutorial online but I have one issue with this piece of code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;


namespace PhoneApp4
{
public partial class CompassScreen : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Compass compass = new Compass();
    RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform();
    double TrueHeading;
    double ReciprocalHeading;
    double HeadingAccuracy;
    bool Alphabetic = false; //alpha output setting, default is false
    bool Calibrating = false;

     // Constructor
    public CompassScreen()
  {
       try
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            compass.CurrentValueChanged += new      EventHandler<SensorReadingEventArgs<CompassReading>>(compass_CurrentValueChanged);
            compass.Calibrate += new EventHandler<CalibrationEventArgs>(compass_Calibrate);
```

When I do it as a an app that only displays the compass the app works fine, if I want to 
incorporate in an app that have few windows it does not work the part ".CurentValueChanged" and ".Calibrate" is underlined in red, the last 2 lines.

```
compass.CurrentValueChanged
compass.Calibrate
```

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
R.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**the documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.compass.aspx#events), those events do not exist on the class elaborated for Windows 8 devices. The only event you may listen for (which is equivalent to CurrentValueChanged) is [**ReadingChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.compass.readingchanged.aspx).